# Proof that $|\mathscr{F}_1 \cap \mathscr{F}_2| \geq \frac{|\mathscr{F}_1| \cdot |\mathscr{F}_2|}{2^n}$

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, hypergraphs

A subsets family $\mathscr{F}$ of set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is called hereditary set if for any $A \in \mathscr{F}$ and any $B \subset A,$ $ \ B \in \mathscr{F}$.

Proof that $|\mathscr{F}_1 \cap \mathscr{F}_2| \geq \frac{|\mathscr{F}_1| \cdot |\mathscr{F}_2|}{2^n}$ holds if $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$ are hereditary sets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

It is possible to solve this problem with pure math induction, but I don't have any idea how to do it. Could somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a result due to Kleitman.

You will find a proof by induction in this [draft book](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Ekpanagio/draft.pdf) page 101 Theorem 10.6.

About the mathematical accomplishments of Kleitman see [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82754199.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Jean Marie, the proof looks great. I've got a question though. Could you explain why $|A \cap B| = |A_0 \cap B_0| + |A_1 \cap B_1|$?

Comment: Good question. I must have a closer look... in particular to the previous page.

Comment: @RomanDryndik We have the disjoint union $A = A_0 \times \{0\} \cup A_1 \times \{1\}$, similarly for $B$. Therefore you get $A \cap B = (A_0 \times \{0\} \cup A_1 \times \{1\}) \cap (B_0 \times \{0\} \cup B_1 \times \{1\})$ which after a bit of messaging is $(A_0 \cap B_0) \times \{ 0 \} \cup (A_1 \cap B_1) \times \{ 1 \}$. The result then follows, since we again have a disjoint union at the end.

Comment: @Lereau A big thank.